# Why does Owin Startup order affect Cookie Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin

I have Owin configured to issue both a token and cookie upon authentication:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var cookieOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
        CookieHttpOnly = true, // JavaScript should use the Bearer
        //AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        CookieName = "MyCookie",
        LoginPath = new PathString("/app/index.html#/login"),
    };

    var oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
        Provider = new MyAuthorizationServerProvider(),
    };

    var oAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
    };

    // Must be registered in this order!
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOptions);
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(oAuthBearerOptions);
 }
```

This works fine - it issues both the Bearer token for my SPA to call my API and the cookie so my old school MVC pages can be logged in too.

But if I register the OAuth server before declaring that I want to use CookieAuth, no cookie is issued.  In other words if I do this, it doesn't work:

```
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieOptions);
app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(oAuthBearerOptions);
```

Also, if I uncomment this line, it also doesn't issue the cookie:

```
AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
```

My question is why does the order of registration with Owin matter?  And why does setting the AuthenticationType in the cookie as `"ApplicationCookie"` also make it fail?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with the `UseOAuthAuthorizationServer()` middleware, but I assume it works the same as other external authentication middleware (e.g. the Google middleware).

An authentication middleware that redirects to an external source for authentication, will only be used once, at the start, of each browsing session. It will then defer the authentication of the up-coming requests to a cookie authentication that maintains the session. This is good, because it means the overhead of the external authentication is only done once for each session.

A middleware that wants to set a cookie does typically not do it itself. Instead it sets a property in the Owin context with an `AuthenticationResponseGrant`. The grant is then processed by the cookie middleware that extracts the identity and sets the cookie.

For this to work:

1. The cookie handler must be registered before the external authentication middleware in the pipeline.
2. The authentication type in the `AuthenticationResponseGrant` must match the type of the cookie middleware.

So changing the order of the registration violates 1. and excluding the authentication type violates 2.

I have written an [in depth blog post](http://coding.abel.nu/2014/06/understanding-the-owin-external-authentication-pipeline/) about it if you want more details.

Comment: Anders Abel, I read your entire OWIN series and it is an excellent introduction!  I wish I had found it before I started rather than the myriad of confusing resources that I found.

Comment: To follow up, my case is similar to what the Visual Studio built in SPA template does - it supports cookie authorization for MVC pages and Bearer Tokens for API.  Anyway, by your argument in (1), shouldn't the OAuthBearerAuthentication also be before OAuthAuthorizationServer in the pipeline?

Comment: I don't know the details of how OAuthBearerAuthentication and OAuthAuthorizationServer interacts and if the latter is dependent on the former, so I can't answer that.